# Couchbase Community Edition as a Cache

Tags: cache, memcache, couchbase

It is mentioned here(www.couchbase.com/memcached) that couchbase can be used as the caching layer. I am supposed to use the community edition for my caching layer. As found in Internet, there are many large scale organizatios are using for heavy usage, but the size of their caches are around 1kb to 100kb. I want to know,

1.will there be a performance draw backs when large objects(1mb-10mb size) are cached and when it is replicated ?
2.will data be synchronized/replicated among nodes as soon as they are updated

any one has experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can have up to 20MB objects in a couchbase type bucket.
   See http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#data-storage
2. Yes data does replicate when an object is updated. Default is asynchronous replication and that’s one of the reason why couchbase is so fast. How fast replication is depends on hardware and usage.

   See point #9 at http://blog.couchbase.com/10-things-developers-should-know-about-couchbase.

   But you can however do synchronous updates. But you trade in performance for data-safety and wait until the document has been saved to disk and/or replicated to other hosts.

Comment: Thank you Raboo your explanation. But, would you let me explain more please this. you also mentioned that "until the document has... ". My objects are not always document types. They are always serialized objects. Then will there be a performance difference or any other impact? As far as I know, the client itself sends byte array to server to cache right ? If I cache my objects as byte arrays, then no problem will occur.?

Comment: tbh I don't really know. That goes outside the scope of my knowledge.
You would have to check out couchbase sdk/api perhaps.

Comment: I tested with 5mb objects to cache concurrently. But it failed when many objects are cached rapidly. :( It just throw time out exceptions. Here I posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181981/couchbase-client-time-out

Comment: But you should be able to set the timeout value in the client. It all depends on usage. If you have 5MB objects and you would do 1000 request at once, then you would request or send 5GB of data.. So I guess that would depend on how you scale it. Are you sure you didn't hit any resource limits like network or other.. I have around 60k ops per second with 1-2KB average document size without any issues on a 7 node cluster.